# Using regular expression, how to remove matching sequence at the beginning and ending of the text but keeping what's in the middle?

Tags: java, regex, ansi-escape

my problem is very simple but I can't figure out the correct regular expression I should use.

I have the following variable (Java) :

```java
String text = "\033[1mYO\033[0m"; // this is ANSI for bold text in the Terminal
```

My goal is to remove the ANSI codes with a single regular expression (I just want to keep the plain text at the middle). I cannot modify the text in any way and those ANSI codes will always be at the same place (so one at the beginning, one at the end, though sometimes it's possible that there is none).

With this regular expression, I will remove them using `replaceAll` method :

```java
String plainText = text.replaceAll(unknownRegex, "");
```

Any idea on what the unknown regex could be?

Comment: To the guy that deleted his comment : Yeah, right, i had not thought about that. Using a group to get what's in the middle and using it to replace the whole string it's a very good idea, thank you!

Comment: The unknown regex could be [`\033\[[01]m`](https://regex101.com/r/4aXP7u/1/codegen?language=java) (Java demo)

Comment: You're right, @bobblebubble but there might be other digits instead of 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you use a single regex that has the ansi codes optionally at the beginning and end, captures anything in between and replaces the entire string with the value of the group: `text.replaceAll("^(?:\\\\\\d+\\[1m)?(.*?)(?:\\\\\\d+\\[0m)?$", "$1")`. (this might not capture every ansi code - adjust if needed).

Breaking the expression down (note that the example above escapes backslashes for Java strings so they are doubled):

- `^` is the start of the string
- `(?:\\\d+\[1m)?` matches an optional `\<at least 1 digit>[1m`
- `(.*?)` matches any text but as little as possible, and captures it into group 1
- `(?:\\\d+\[0m)?` atches an optional `\<at least 1 digit>[0m`
- `$` is the end of the input

In the replacement `$1` refers to the value of capturing group 1 which is `(.*?)` in the expression.

Comment: I don't think that the scary "\\\\\\d+\\" is needed as I could just use "\\033\\[.*m" and my problem solved anyway. Maybe your solution works for more situations though much harder to read and understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Found the answer thanks to a comment that disappeared.*

Actually, i just need to make a group to get what's in the middle of the string and using it ($1) to replace the whole thing :

```java
String plainText = text.replaceAll("\\033\\[.*m(.+)\\033\\[.*m", "$1")
```

Not sure if this will remove every ANSI codes but that is enough for what I want to do.

Comment: I removed that comment to post it as an answer for better formatting :)

Comment: Right, I guess I was quicker lmao, thanks bro